# quasiquote/quote in lua?

Tags: lua

In Lisp, I can have:

```
(a b c d e f g)
```

which means

```
look up b, c, d, e, f, g
look up a; apply value of a to above
```

Then, I can also have:

```
`(a b c d e f g)
```

which is the equiv to

```
 (list 'a 'b 'c 'd 'e 'f 'g)
```

Now, in lua, I can have:

```
[snipplet 1]
foo = {
  Foo,
  {Cat, cat},
  {Dog, dog}
};
```

Which ends up most likely expanding into:
    { nil, { nil, nil}, {nil, nil}}

Whereas what I really want is something like:

```
[snipplet 2]
{ "Foo", {"Cat", "cat"}, {"Dog", "dog"}}
```

Is there some backquote-like method in lua?

I find [snipplet 1] to be more visually pleasing than [snipplet 2], but what I mean is snipplet 2.

Thanks!

Comment: Coming back to this question seven years later, one thing I notice is that the example table appears to be using a list of key-value pairs for item properties: I wonder if the asker may not have realized that Lua tables can have string keys, so their example table would have been better written as `{'Foo', Cat='cat', Dog='dog'}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no syntax for that but you can try this run-time solution:

```
setmetatable(_G,{__index=function (t,k) return k end})
```

This makes all undefined variables behave as if they contained strings with their names.

Comment: The trick is kinda cute, but it has the problem that if the value is defined, I get the value, which can be a subtle bug to track down.

Comment: Just evaluate the expression in an empty environment then, with the metatable above set.

Comment: The trouble then is with closures.

Comment: You can also do `local q = setmetatable(_G,{__index=function (t,k) return k end})` to make an object for quote-names like `q.Cat` (which would return "Cat").

Answer (score 0):

Consider a function that parses a string containing the Lisp syntax and constructs a table from that.