# quoting troubles in Lua

Tags: lua

I am trying to make a quote function in lua, so i can use the arguments as strings but without quotes or access them in some environment. Much like in the second comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747445/quasiquote-quote-in-lua)

```
w = print
function test()
   local function _ix( _ , k )
w( "              _ix \\ " , _ , k )
            local v = rawget( _G , k )
w( "              <-- " , k )
         return k
         end
  local _ = setmetatable( {} , { __index = _ix } )
  local function q( _ )    return _  end
        q = setfenv( q , _ )
return q
end
```

So, when I run it:

```
q = test()
w( "q( uno )" , q( uno ) )
```

It doesn't even call the __index metamethod:

```
---------- Capture Output ----------

q( uno )    nil

> Terminated with exit code 0.
```

So, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Start by using sensible variable names, formatting, and less self-induced indirection.

Comment: @oka I made an edit which made the code as readable as I could make out. Once it's applied globally it should be far easier to read.

Comment: @warspyking Your edit has clear conflicts with the original code. You can rewrite the original like [this](https://repl.it/EIW1), but it's still nonsensical in that it's trying to look things up in the wrong order. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, then what you're trying to do doesn't make much sense. `uno` will be looked up in the environment that `q` is called *in*, not *with*. In your example it's like calling `q(nil)`. The example from the other question works because they're working in the same, global environment.

You can use write a helper function to intercept your current environments `nil`-lookups, but it must be called preemptively in any environment you want to use these `nil`-to-`string` lookups.

```
local function intercept (tab)
    setfenv(2, setmetatable(tab or {}, {
        __index = function (_, key)
            return key
        end
    }))
end
```

And you'll need an environment cloning function, unless you want to manually create your sandboxes every time, else you'll probably mess up parent environments (e.g., `_G`). You could move this logic inside of `intercept` for a cleaner function call, but with less flexibility.

```
local function clone_current_env ()
    local env = {}

    for key, value in pairs(getfenv(2)) do
        env[key] = value
    end

    return env
end
```

Using them together, you can cause `nil` lookups in whichever environment you're in to become strings.

```
intercept(clone_current_env())
print(type(foo), type(bar)) --> string string
```

This is some *ugly* metaprogramming, and I don't really know *why* you'd want to write code like this, except as a proof of concept.

---

A full example.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://repl.it/EIWn)</kbd>

```
local function clone (tab)
    local new = {}

    for key, value in pairs(tab) do
        new[key] = value
    end

    return new
end

local function enable_nil_strings ()
    setfenv(2, setmetatable(clone(getfenv(2)), {
        __index = function (env, key)
            return key
        end 
    }))
end

local function disable_nil_strings()
    setmetatable(getfenv(2), nil)
end

-----------------------------------------------------

print(type(foo), type(bar)) --> nil nil
enable_nil_strings()
print(type(foo), type(bar)) --> string string
disable_nil_strings()
print(type(foo), type(bar)) --> nil nil
```

---

Finally, arguably the best way to implement this would be to simply wrap around an execution context:

```
local function with_nil_strings (context, ...)
    local env = {}

    for key, value in pairs(getfenv(2)) do
        env[key] = value
    end

    setfenv(
        context,
        setmetatable(env, {
            __index = function (_, key) return key end 
        })
    )

    context(...)
end

print(type(foo)) --> nil

with_nil_strings(function ()
    print(type(foo)) --> string
end)

print(type(foo)) --> nil
```